# How can I reput task in task queue as it failed while using ThreadPoolExecutor Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from  package `concurrent.futures` and want to do batch request concurrently.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
import requests


BASE_URL = "api/{param_id}"

def get_result(param_id):
    url = BASE_URL.format(param_id=param_id)
    s = requests.get(url)
    return s
    # if task failed here, how can I reput it into task_queue again until it 
    # return expected result successfully

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    obj_list = []
    result_list = []
    for page in range(1, 15):
        obj = executor.submit(get_result, page)
        obj_list.append(obj)

    for future in as_completed(obj_list):
        data = future.result()
        result_list.append(data)
```

`ThreadPoolExecutor` itself implemented the `queue` inside. My question is how can I reput task `get_result` into this `queue` again as it failed due to some network timeout issue or other unexpected problem.

Great thanks.